# How to declare and add items to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to add items to an array in Python.

I run

```py
array = {}
```

Then, I try to add something to this array by doing:

```py
array.append(valueToBeInserted)
```

There doesn't seem to be an `.append` method for this. How do I add items to an array?

Answer (score 850, accepted):

`{}` represents an empty dictionary, not an array/list.  For lists or arrays, you need `[]`.

To initialize an empty list do this:

```
my_list = []
```

or

```
my_list = list()
```

To add elements to the list, use `append`

```
my_list.append(12)
```

To `extend` the list to include the elements from another list use `extend`

```
my_list.extend([1,2,3,4])
my_list
--> [12,1,2,3,4]
```

To remove an element from a list use `remove`

```
my_list.remove(2)
```

Dictionaries represent a collection of key/value pairs also known as an associative array or a map.

To initialize an empty dictionary use `{}` or `dict()`

Dictionaries have keys and values

```
my_dict = {'key':'value', 'another_key' : 0}
```

To extend a dictionary with the contents of another dictionary you may use the `update` method

```
my_dict.update({'third_key' : 1})
```

To remove a value from a dictionary

```
del my_dict['key']
```

Comment: Oh ok, I understood it as a list would need to have a key and a value, but I guess not

Answer (score 65):

If you do it this way:

```
array = {}
```

you are making a dictionary, not an array.

If you need an array (which is called a list in python ) you declare it like this:

```
array = []
```

Then you can add items like this:

```
array.append('a')
```

Comment: Nitpicking: You don't *declare* anything. You make a name in the current scope refer to a dictionary/list object.

Answer (score 19):

Arrays (called `list` in python) use the `[]` notation. `{}` is for `dict` (also called hash tables, associated arrays, etc in other languages) so you won't have 'append' for a dict.

If you actually want an array (list), use:

```
array = []
array.append(valueToBeInserted)
```

Answer (score 16):

Just for sake of completion, you can also do this:

```
array = []
array += [valueToBeInserted]
```

If it's a list of strings, this will also work:

```
array += 'string'
```

Comment: Would there be performance impact between `array = += [value]` and `array.append(value)`?

Answer (score 3):

In some languages like **JAVA** you define an array using curly braces as following but in python it has a different meaning:

**Java:**

```
int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3};
String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c"};
```

However, in Python, curly braces are used to define dictionaries, which needs a `key:value` assignment as `{'a':1, 'b':2}`

To actually define an array (which is actually called list in python) you can do:

**Python:**

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

or other examples like:

```
mylist = list()
mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(2)
mylist.append(3)
print(mylist)
>>> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
array = numpy.append(array, value)
```

Note that the `numpy.append()` method returns a new object, so if you want to modify your initial array, you have to write: `array = ...`

Comment: Definitely not a good idea to use `numpy` to append to an array and, in the process, create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

##### `extend()` by a singleton

It's purely academic but `extend()` method can be used to append a value to a list as well. Simply wrap the value in a tuple/list and extend the list by it.

```py
lst = []
value = 1
lst.extend((value,))    # <--- (value,) is a singleton tuple
```

As it happens, it's faster than `iadd` (`+= [1]`)-ing a singleton list. In fact, it performs the same as `list.append`. See the results [here](https://tio.run/##hVFfa4MwEH/3UwRfvDAJRNvaUXzZ1yh9yOqxZlQN8Qr107uLzjJpux4kkON@/3Kup1Pb5MNga9d6EmRrtBSRFqWobQPTW3l0aAjic0fKOIdNBVrGqeAKPR7eH2IpI8qe4sQbD@nDBLrD5c/18EpBD3Qqg@QSt3qJY83R6QIXOW8bAtKpoIxPzmfFbVr/698S1t2c4Ea4m/rlntmyydbmpa0RsshzTzO7XLO7DT87pIvj2fh3WcZ70@8EE5Rn2xF403whvBepznL@q4iKxzaSRH233K6Ng@PJp4FByttm/tYoGRJtH1ONFtR4Q/KRTFSK2s@esAOpKjy2FUIgn6nmVAWn2sph@AE). Also, since it's faster to build a tuple than a list, extending by a singleton tuple is faster than by a singleton list.

```py
import timeit
t1 = min(timeit.repeat("lst.append(1)",    "lst = []"))   # 0.058306435006670654 
t2 = min(timeit.repeat("lst += [1]",       "lst = []"))   # 0.08136546600144356 
t3 = min(timeit.repeat("lst.extend((1,))", "lst = []"))   # 0.05731289298273623 
t4 = min(timeit.repeat("lst.extend([1])",  "lst = []"))   # 0.1094264310086146
```

---

However, if the list is not a singleton, `iadd` (`+=`) is very competitive in terms of performance compared to `list.extend` as the following experiment shows.

```py
t5 = min(timeit.repeat("lst += items",      "lst = []; items=[1, 2]"))  # 0.033552975044585764 
t6 = min(timeit.repeat("lst.extend(items)", "lst = []; items=[1, 2]"))  # 0.060612224973738194
```

##### Python's [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

The standard library also has the `array` module, which is a wrapper over C arrays. Like C arrays, `array.array` objects hold only a single type (which has to be specified at object creation time by using a type code), whereas Python `list` objects can hold anything. It also defines `append`/`extend`/`remove` etc. to manipulate the data. It's useful if there is a need to interface with C arrays.

```py
import array

arr = array.array('f')  # initialize a float array
arr.append(1)           # append 1.0 to it (because its type is float)
arr.extend([2, 3])      # extend it by multiple values
lst = arr.tolist()      # convert to list

arr                     # array('f', [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
lst                     # [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]


# `arr` only accepts floats; `lst` doesn't have that restriction
lst.append('string')       # <---- OK
arr.append('string')       # <---- TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

The main advantage of `array.array` objects over `list`s is memory-efficiency. As you can see from the example below, `arr` consumes roughly 10 times less memory than `lst`.

```py
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof

lst = list(range(1_000_000))
arr = array.array('I', lst)

asizeof(lst)       # 40000048
asizeof(arr)       # 4000064
```

In special cases, working with `array.array` objects may be faster than working with lists. There's [an anecdote on the Python website](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) that gives one such example. It's about converting a list of integers into strings. A modern version could look like below (converting to `array.array` is still faster than `str.join`).

```py
setup = "import array; lst=list(range(97,123))"
t8 = min(timeit.repeat("''.join(map(chr, lst))",                   setup))  # 2.106592966010794
t9 = min(timeit.repeat("array.array('B', lst).tobytes().decode()", setup))  # 1.2953468860359862
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a good idea to learn how to create an array in the most **performant way**?

It's really simple to create and insert an values into an array:

```
my_array = ["B","C","D","E","F"]
```

But, now we have two ways to insert one more value into this array:

Slow mode:

`my_array.insert(0,"A")` - moves all values ​​to the right when entering an "A" in the zero position:

```
"A" --> "B","C","D","E","F"
```

Fast mode:

my_array.append("A")

Adds the value "A" to the last position of the array, without touching the other positions:

```
"B","C","D","E","F", "A"
```

If you need to display the sorted data, do so later when necessary. Use the way that is most useful to you, but it is interesting to understand the performance of each method.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you are all wrong. you need to do:

`array = array[]` in order to define it, and then:

`array.append ["hello"]` to add to it.

Comment: The correct way of defining an array is `array = []`

Comment: You can also define it using `array = list()`. Note defining it as an array using [] provides specific functionality only available to arrays such as array division by a single integer. Ex. `array/3`

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Just stick to list when using python