# Appending a string to a list using a for loop where each item is appended is a new string

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to create a new create a list where a new item is appended to the list through each iteration of a for loop. The code so far looks like such:

```
path_start = 'https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin'
file = ".csv"

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("10-02-2007", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("21-02-2019", "%d-%m-%Y")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

date_list = []

for date in date_generated:
    date_string = date.strftime("%d%m%Y")
    for path_name in date_string:
        x = path_start + date_string + file
        date_list.append(x)

print(date_list)
```

When I do this a list is created but each item in the list is identical. I want each item to use the date_string variable created in the previous for loop which should change in each iteration. This is an example of the list it creates:

```
['https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin10022007.csv', 'https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin10022007.csv'
```

I have tried changing the indentation of the loops but this did not solve the problem.

I also tried to increase the efficiency using numpy array but the answer to this question ([How to declare and add items to an array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487278/how-to-declare-and-add-items-to-an-array-in-python)) said to use a list. Since the list is particularly long any help to increase efficiency would also be appreciated.

Cheers,
Sandy

Comment: `path_start, date_string, file` don't change inside `for path_name in date_string:`.

Comment: Is the `numpy` tag there because you would prefer/consider a NumPy solution?

Comment: What do you need the inner loop for?

Comment: Yes, I thought this might be able to increase the efficiency but I am not sure how to add new items to numpy array

Comment: @Austin Cheers! I've taken the second loop out and its working now. Overthinking ah!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies here:

```
for path_name in date_string:
```

The `date_string` is a string value at this point. Your `path_name` variable, which is not used inside the loop, is iterating character-by-character through the string.

This means you will have 8 values (ddmmyyyy= 8 chars) for each entry. If you look at every eighth entry in the resulting list, you will probably see changes.

I don't think you need the inner loop at all. Try just this:

```
for date in date_generated:
    date_string = date.strftime("%d%m%Y")
    x = path_start + date_string + file
    date_list.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

you only need change the for loop like this:

```
date_list = []
for date in date_generated:
    date_list.append(path_start + date.strftime("%Y%m%d") + file)

print(date_list)
```

output example:

```
[...'https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin20190124.csv',... 'https://promo.betfair.com/betfairsp/prices/dwbfpricesukwin20190219.csv'...]
```

**NOTE:** The second loop is not necessary because you no need loop over the date_string, you need apend the date to the string name