# while writing a code for fibonacci series, the problem I'm facing is that index error

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def calc_fib(n):
    arr=list()
    arr[2]=1
    arr[1]=1
    for i in range(3,n):
        arr[i]=arr[i-2]+arr[i-1]
    return arr[n]
n = int(input())
print(calc_fib(n))
```

here, is the error showing up.....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in calc_fib
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare and add items to an array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487278/how-to-declare-and-add-items-to-an-array-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

the maximum of the index of python array is `n-1`, so you should return `a[n-1]` and `i` between `(2, n)`, maybe this one is better:

```
import numpy as np
def calc_fib(n):
    arr=np.zeros(n)
    arr[1]=1
    arr[0]=1
    for i in range(2,n):
        arr[i]=arr[i-2]+arr[i-1]
    return arr[n-1]
n = int(input())
print(calc_fib(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you can modify. You should start the index from 0 and end at n-1.

```
def calc_fib(n):
   arr=list()
   arr = [0,1]
   for i in range(2,n):
       arr.append(arr[i-2]+arr[i-1])
       return arr[n-1]
n = int(input())
print(calc_fib(n))
```